# How to solve $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(x-1)\ln x}{(x+1)(x^2+2\cosh \alpha+1)} \,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

I have this unpleasant integral that appear in my last exam which i was not able solve

> For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate $$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(x-1)\ln x}{(x+1)(x^2+2\cosh \alpha+1)} \,dx$$

Anyway my attempt is that I try to do some partial fraction on the integral

$$\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)(x^2+2\cosh \alpha+1)} = \frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)(x+\cosh \alpha-\sinh \alpha)(x+\cosh \alpha+\sinh \alpha)}$$

$$\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)(x+\cosh \alpha-\sinh \alpha)(x+\cosh \alpha+\sinh \alpha)}=\frac{a}{x+1}+\frac{b}{x+\cosh \alpha-\sinh \alpha}+\frac{c}{x+\cosh \alpha+\sinh \alpha}$$

And I find that

$$a=\frac{1}{\cosh \alpha-1}, b=c=\frac{1}{2-2\cosh \alpha}$$

That's all I could do. I still don't know what to do next

Comment: You were very close to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so unpleasant. To make things easier (at least to me), consider
$$\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x^2+k)}=\frac{x-1}{(x+1) (x-a) (x-b)}$$ and, as you did, using partial fraction decomposition, this becomes
$$\frac{a-1}{(a+1) (a-b) (x-a)}-\frac{2}{(a+1) (b+1) (x+1)}+\frac{b-1}{(b+1) (b-a)   (x-b)}$$ One integration by parts leads to
$$\int\frac {\log(x)}{x+c} dx=\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{x}{c}\right)+\log (x) \log \left(1+\frac{x}{c}\right)$$
$$\int_0^1\frac {\log(x)}{x+c} dx=\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{c}\right)$$ Combining all of the above
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{(x-1)\log(x)}{(x+1) (x-a) (x-b)}=$$
$$\frac{6 (a-1) (b+1) \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)-6 (a+1) (b-1)
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)+\pi ^2 (a-b)}{6 (a+1) (b+1) (a-b)}$$

As you found
$$a=-e^{-\alpha} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=-e^{\alpha}$$ Replacing leads to
$$I=-\frac{e^{\alpha } \left(6 \text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-\alpha }\right)+6
   \text{Li}_2\left(-e^{\alpha }\right)+\pi ^2\right)}{6 \left(e^{\alpha
   }-1\right)^2}$$ which *looks like* a gaussian.

Comment: I usually see a lot of weird function (just like what you provided) that people have used to solve an integral. Is there any particular name for this kind of function? I would like to know more about them. Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @user635988. You were very close to the solution. In my humble opinion, first, get rid of the constant, then factorize even if you do not know what could be the roots (name them $(a,b,c,d,\cdots)$). Then partial fraction decomposition even if you do not know what are the coefficients (name them $(A,B,C,D,\cdots)$). Now, you face standard integrals.

Comment: With the inversion formula, $\text{Li}_2(-z)+\text{Li}_2(-1/z)=2\text{Li}_2(-1)-\ln(z)^2/2$, $$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha/2}{\sinh\alpha/2}\right)^{2}$$